# Defining global collection of variables in R

Tags: r, grouping, lm

In Stata, one can define a global like `global PETS cats dogs rabbits mice` which collects these variables in some bucket named `PETS`. One can then use this in

```
reg happiness $PETS
```

which effectively runs `reg happiness cats dogs rabbits mice`. Is there an equivalent for this in R that allows something like `m <- lm(happiness ~ PETS + other_variable)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this workaround:

```
PETS <- c("dogs", "rabbits", "mice")
m <- lm( as.formula( paste( "happiness ~ other_variable +", paste(PETS, collapse=" + ") ) ) )
```

Answer (score 3):

You should study `help("formula")`. I assume your variables are in a data.frame. If they aren't, well, they should be.

A reproducible example using the build-in `iris` data set:

```
predictors <- c("Sepal.Width", "Petal.Length")

fit <- lm(Sepal.Length ~ ., data = iris[, c("Sepal.Length", predictors)])
summary(fit)
```

As you see, I use `DV ~ .` to regress on all variables and subset the data.frame passed to `lm` to the columns of interest.

Comment: Yes, all variables are in a data.frame. This sort of collection that I have in mind is merely for convenience. Imagine you want to fit 10-15 models with _some_ controls varying but with a group of others always included (sort of a baseline specification.